# Flutter web: Launch page in target="_self" with url_launcher

Tags: hyperlink, flutter-web

I am using [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package.

When in Flutter web, I would like the url to be opened in the current page, and not in `target="_blank"`

I tried adding `forceWebView: true,`

```
if (await canLaunch(url)) {
  await launch(
    url,
    forceSafariVC: true,
    forceWebView: true,
    headers: <String, String>{'target': '_self'},
  );
} else {
  throw 'Could not launch $url';
}
```

And also added headers thinking they might have something to do, but they don't.

Is there a way to do this? Thank you

Any other solution to open a url in mobile and in web, and that enables the possiblity to open the web link in self is accepted also

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In flutter_web if you want to achieve this you can use the `webOnlyWindowName` property and pass `_self` or `_blank` depending on your choice.

- `_self` - opens in the same tab.
- `_blank` - opens in a new tab.

I am not sure if its documented properly. But you can find the piece of code responsible for this [here](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/b597aba597e511afad7ff5f34e981cf15e331232/packages/url_launcher/url_launcher_web/lib/url_launcher_web.dart#L83).

Following is a working solution which you can test.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(UrlLauchDemo());
}

class UrlLauchDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  String url = 'https://www.google.com';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              MaterialButton(
                color: Colors.greenAccent,
                child: Text('Launch Google in this page'),
                onPressed: () async {
                  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
                    await launch(
                      url,
                      forceSafariVC: true,
                      forceWebView: true,
                      webOnlyWindowName: '_self',
                    );
                  } else {
                    throw 'Could not launch $url';
                  }
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 100,
              ),
              MaterialButton(
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                child: Text('Launch Google in new Tab'),
                onPressed: () async {
                  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
                    await launch(
                      url,
                      forceSafariVC: true,
                      forceWebView: true,
                      webOnlyWindowName: '_blank',
                    );
                  } else {
                    throw 'Could not launch $url';
                  }
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Update: 12.01.2021**
This information is documented in the api documentation [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/url_launcher/launch.html)

Comment: Great, this worked, I have to wait 19 hours to give the bounty