# Flutter Web - Open external url in same tab

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have Flutter Web app and I need to redirect the user out of my app (to a facebook login form) that eventually will redirect the user back to my app. My problem is that I can't open that external url in the same tab with url_launcher (https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) because this library launch the url in a new tab and I end up with 2 browser tabs both with my app on it. I tried to use an WebView but the X-Frame options for facebook are set on 'sameorigin' and can't be displayed into an iframe (what the webview does). I need a solution that allows me to redirect the user to Facebook login in the same tab (without using facebook_login_web plugin because I use Spring Social on the server side for this).

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64653342/flutter-web-launch-page-in-target-self-with-url-launcher) might already have an answer for you.

Comment: Thank you a lot guys. I don't know how you find this :)) I had researched this issue for some hours and I couldn't find this thread.

Comment: Because I remember writing the answer. :)

Comment: Hahahaha, didn't notice. Thanks again.